# storing form data into a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have created a form in html and I want to store its data inserted by the user in a JSON file in the form of json objects & arrays, I am new with json & javascript so kindly tell how can I do this?

**this is my html form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
    First name:<input type="text" name="firstname">Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
    Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender">male<input type="radio" name="gender">female<br>
    Married: <input type="checkbox" name="married">yes<input type="checkbox" name="merried">no<br>
    Degree:
    <select>
        <option>BS</option>
        <option>MS</option>
        <option>PhD</option>
    </select>
    Description: <textarea style="width:200px"></textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**and I want the output *.json* file like this:**

```
[
    {
        "first name": "adam",
        "last name": "smith"
        "gender": "male",
        "merried": "yes"
        "degree": "MS",
        "description": "any discription"

    },
    {
        "first name": "anglina",
        "last name": "jouley"
        "gender": "female",
        "merried": "no"
        "degree": "PhD",
        "description": "any discription"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just save it to a file system using javascript and html on frontend side. For that you will need a backend.

> Steps should be:
>
> 1. Serialize form data to json using jQuery or plain javascript.
> 2. Send json data through ajax/xmlhttprequest to a backend server.
> 3. Receive json data at server side and save to a .json file